# Why is hibernate batching / order_inserts / order_updates disabled by default?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, low-latency

Are there any reasons why hibernate batching / hibernate.order_updates / hibernate.order_inserts are disabled by default? Is there any disadvantage when you enable a batch size of 50? Same for the order_updates / order_inserts parameters. Is there a use case where you shouldn't enable these features? Are there any performance impacts when using these features?

I can only see that these settings help a lot when I need to reduce my query count which is necessary especially in a cloud environment with high latencies between my application and database server.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Generally, setting `batch size` to reasonable size and `order_insert`, `order_updates` to `true` can significantly improve performance.

In all my projects, I use this configuration as basis:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 100
hibernate.order_inserts   = true 
hibernate.order_updates   = true
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size = 400
```

But, **yes** - there can be **memory impact** when using batching. But this depends on jdbc driver.

For example, Oracle JDBC driver creates internal buffers for each `PreparedStatement` and reuses these buffers. If you call simple update statement you set some parameters with `ps.setInt(1, ...)`, `ps.setString(2, ...)` etc, and Oracle converts this values to some byte representation and stores in buffer associated with this `PreparedStatement` and connection.

However, when your `PreparedStatement` uses batch of size 100, this buffer will be 100 times larger. And if you have some connection pool with for exapmle 50 connections there can be 50 such big buffers. And if you have 100 different statements using batching all such buffers can have significant memory impact. When you enable batch size, it becomes global setting - Hibernate will use it for all insert/updates.

However, I found that in all my projects performance gain was more important that this memory impact and that is why I use `batchsize=100` as my default.

With `order_inserts`, `order_updates`, I think that these are disabled by default, because these settings make sense only when batching is on. With batching set off, these ordering is simply overhead.

You can find more info in Oracle's white paper:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/memory.pdf

in section *"Statement Batching and Memory Use"*.

==== EDIT 2016.05.31 ====

A word about `order_inserts` and `order_udpates` property.
Let's say we have entities `A`, `B` and persist 6 objects this way:

```
session.save(A1);  // added to action queue
session.save(B1);  // added to action queue
session.save(A2);  // ...
session.save(B2);  // ...
session.save(A3);  // ...
session.save(B3);  // ...
```

after above execution:

- these 6 objects has identifiers generated
- these 6 objects are connected to session (StatefulPersistenceContext: entitiesByKey, entityEntries, etc. /Hib.v3/)
- these 6 objects are added to ActionQueue in the same order: [A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3]

Now, consider 2 cases:

**case 1:** `order_inserts = false`

during flush phase, hibernate performs **6 insert** statements:

```
ActionQueue = [A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3]
insert into A - (A1)
insert into B - (B1)
insert into A - (A2)
insert into B - (B2)
insert into A - (A3)
insert into B - (B3)
```

**case 2:** `order_inserts = true`, batching allowed

now, during flush phase, hibernate performs **2 batch insert** statements:

```
ActionQueue = [A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3]
insert into A -  (A1, A2, A3)
insert into B -  (B1, B2, B3)
```

I investigated this for Hibernate v3, I think Hibernate v4 uses ActionQueue in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch

says there may be a performance penalty for using these properties.  I would assume this is the reason they are not set by default.

Comment: can you provide a replacement for the broken link ?